# Looper Of the Android varies on devices

Tags: android

I have some strange behaviours. On Samsung S6, my app crashes with `Looper` exception where it says can't create handler inside thread that does not call `looper.prepare()`.

That is OK, I understand and same happening on LG, but what is the weirdest part is that I got Huawei p8 lite and Google Nexus 6 where I do not get that crash.

By Googling I could not find any resources.

I am just simply making a Toast there and the variety really confuses me.The question is why i get crash on samsung and lg but on huawei and nexus i did not?

Comment: you shouldn't call Toast from a non-UI thread.

Comment: I know that i just miswatched it but the question is why on samsung and lg i get the crash and on nexus and huawei i did not?

Comment: you should not do any UI stuff from none UI thread. period.

Comment: Let me please update the question

Comment: did you double check which `Thread` are you in on huawei and nexus? maybe its simply the UI one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly answer to that question, one would have to know implementation details of these modified Android versions. AFAIK the correct behaviour is that the exception should be thrown if a looper was created from a bare thread.

Is the handler working on Nexus and Huawei? Were you able to post and execute runnables using that handler? Maybe it's failing silently. Maybe it's internally calling Looper.prepare() ? You can debug loopers/handlers using Looper/Handler.dump() . See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#dump(android.util.Printer, java.lang.String) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#dump(android.util.Printer, java.lang.String)

You can always get the main thread's looper by calling `Looper.getMainLooper()`. It should be safe to use in your case.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()

Comment: But  +1 for this i did not know!

Comment: Noe that is fullly satisfying me!Yes i guess there is some ''hacks'' going on there as neither on huawei nor on google nexus the crash not happening so i guess i am still at the point that modified android always losses precision and make ua suffer thought this is the smallest issue imagine the hugest issues with it